# UpdatePanel StackOverFlow Error

Tags: .net, ajax, visual-studio, updatepanel

I'm trying to change an system to net framework 2.0 to 4.6, I have almost everything complete except for an error I'm getting in the control UpdatePanel

```
If Not Page.Master.FindControl("upp_barra") Is Nothing Then
```

Error says

> $exception    {"Se produjo una excepción de tipo
>   'System.StackOverflowException'."}    System.StackOverflowException

In .net 2.0 works any solution?

Comment: VBA has absolutely nothing to do with .NET. Also your question is unanswerable as it stands, the stack just happened to blow up at that place, doesn't mean the recursion is right there.

Comment: You're right I meant VB. the problem is in the change of framework because as I comment in 2.0 works!

Comment: I don't doubt that. The problem is that we don't know anything about the surrounding code, what's calling it, or anything about the context. Or does that one-liner alone throw a SO exception all by itself? If so, please clarify. If not, see [mcve].

Comment: Not much springs to mind from that... Check `<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">` in the Web.Config?

Comment: I checked it and is is still not working, I'll keep finding the error thanks a lot!